# How can I combine text views by looping?

Tags: swift, textview, swiftui

We can create new text views out of several small ones using +, which is an easy way of creating more advanced formatting. For example, this creates three text views in different colors and combines them together:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       Text("Colored ")
           .foregroundColor(.red)
       +
       Text("SwifUI ")
        .foregroundColor(.green)
       +
       Text("Text")
           .foregroundColor(.blue)
   }   
}
```

But how can I create combined text views by looping through. For example (which doesn't work)

```
   View v;
   ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) {
      v.append(Text("\($0)"))
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to get an expression of type `Text`, from a sequence `0...3`. You can first `map` the sequence to `Text` objects. How do you combine a sequence of objects to a single one? `reduce`!

```
(1...3).map { Text("\($0)") }.reduce(Text(""), +)
```

Note that `Text("")` acts like the identity element of the `+` operation.